# Design DataContext not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In a new WP8.1 project I create a ViewModel and use it for design data. My binding does not show the value I expect:

```
namespace App1
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.Name = "hello world";
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get; set;

        }
    }
}

<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In the design surface in Blend or the designer in Visual Studio I see the text "Name" instead of "hello world".

The design-time DataContext of Page should be an instance of my ViewModel and {Binding Name} should be the value of the Name property of my inherited DataContext. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you try in your MainPage something like: this.DataContext = yourViewModelObject?

Answer (score 0):

Per default, `DesignInstance` tries to simulate the data in your viewmodel. If you want to use the real data, you need to set the `IsDesignTimeCreatable` flag:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

Comment: That's right, I forgot to add that in the snippet above, but even with that it doesn't work in my solution. I think there is a problem with the solution configurations and target platforms, because the same code works fine for a Windows 8.1 project. My solution is a universal WP8.1 and Win8.1 solution and only the WP8.1 has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to build non ARM for this to work.

The problem was that I was using the ARM configuration (which I toggle to when I want to deploy to Phone) and that I had changed the x86 configuration to build ARM. So no matter if I had the ARM or x86 configuration selected it would build ARM and thus it wouldn't work.